# MySQL - wrong results when MRR is activated

Tags: mysql, innodb

I dumped a database from a UAT stage and imported it locally.

#### 1. Select with wrong results

Now when I run the following query:

```sql
select
  *
from
  `execution_element_progress`
where
  `execution_element_id` in (
    29412, 29413, 49662, 49663, 49664, 49665, 54520, 54522, 105839, 107267, 107268, 107269, 107270, 107279, 107284, 107285, 107286, 107303, 107304, 107305, 107306, 107307, 107308, 107309, 107310, 107320, 107334, 107427, 107515, 107688, 107689, 107690, 107691, 107692, 107695, 107802, 107803, 107804, 107811, 107812, 107813, 107849
  )
```

I do not get certain records, even though I checked that the `execution_element_id` exists. For instance the one where `execution_element_id` equals `107515`.

##### Debug for this query:

***1.1 EXPLAIN***

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | execution_element_progress |  | range | execution_element_id | execution_element_id | 8 |  | 494 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using MRR |

***1.2 EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON***

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "591.61"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "execution_element_progress",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "execution_element_id"
      ],
      "key": "execution_element_id",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "execution_element_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "8",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 494,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 494,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "index_condition": "(`pm_prod`.`execution_element_progress`.`execution_element_id` in (29412,29413,49662,49663,49664,49665,54520,54522,105839,107267,107268,107269,107270,107279,107284,107285,107286,107303,107304,107305,107306,107307,107308,107309,107310,107320,107334,107427,107515,107688,107689,107690,107691,107692,107695,107802,107803,107804,107811,107812,107813,107849))",
      "using_MRR": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "542.21",
        "eval_cost": "49.40",
        "prefix_cost": "591.61",
        "data_read_per_join": "65K"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "uuid",
        "tenant_id",
        "execution_program_id",
        "execution_element_id",
        "execution_strategic_sprint_id",
        "execution_sprint_id",
        "value",
        "value_percent",
        "total",
        "total_percent",
        "target",
        "target_percent",
        "is_primary_value",
        "is_projection_value",
        "is_detached_from_sprints",
        "deleted_at",
        "deleted_by_user_id",
        "created_at",
        "created_by_user_id",
        "updated_at",
        "updated_by_user_id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***1.3 EXPLAIN ANALYZE***

```
-> Index range scan on execution_element_progress using execution_element_id over (execution_element_id = 29412) OR (execution_element_id = 29413) OR (40 more), with index condition: (execution_element_progress.execution_element_id in (29412,29413,49662,49663,49664,49665,54520,54522,105839,107267,107268,107269,107270,107279,107284,107285,107286,107303,107304,107305,107306,107307,107308,107309,107310,107320,107334,107427,107515,107688,107689,107690,107691,107692,107695,107802,107803,107804,107811,107812,107813,107849))  (cost=592 rows=494) (actual time=1.08..3.06 rows=486 loops=1)
```

#### 2. Select with only one id

The strange thing is if I query only for this one element it works:

```sql
select
      *
    from
      `execution_element_progress`
    where
      `execution_element_id` in (
        107515
      )
```

##### Debug for this query:

***2.1 EXPLAIN***

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | execution_element_progress |  | ref | execution_element_id | execution_element_id | 8 | const | 2 | 100.00 |  |

***2.2 EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON***

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2.19"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "execution_element_progress",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "execution_element_id"
      ],
      "key": "execution_element_id",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "execution_element_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "8",
      "ref": [
        "const"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 2,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 2,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.99",
        "eval_cost": "0.20",
        "prefix_cost": "2.19",
        "data_read_per_join": "272"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "uuid",
        "tenant_id",
        "execution_program_id",
        "execution_element_id",
        "execution_strategic_sprint_id",
        "execution_sprint_id",
        "value",
        "value_percent",
        "total",
        "total_percent",
        "target",
        "target_percent",
        "is_primary_value",
        "is_projection_value",
        "is_detached_from_sprints",
        "deleted_at",
        "deleted_by_user_id",
        "created_at",
        "created_by_user_id",
        "updated_at",
        "updated_by_user_id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***2.3 EXPLAIN ANALYZE***

```
-> Index lookup on execution_element_progress using execution_element_id (execution_element_id=107515)  (cost=2.19 rows=2) (actual time=0.282..0.288 rows=2 loops=1)
```

#### 3. Select with ORDER BY

Another strange thing is, that if I add an **ORDER BY** it also works!

```sql
select
  *
from
  `execution_element_progress`
where
  `execution_element_id` in (
    29412, 29413, 49662, 49663, 49664, 49665, 54520, 54522, 105839, 107267, 107268, 107269, 107270, 107279, 107284, 107285, 107286, 107303, 107304, 107305, 107306, 107307, 107308, 107309, 107310, 107320, 107334, 107427, 107515, 107688, 107689, 107690, 107691, 107692, 107695, 107802, 107803, 107804, 107811, 107812, 107813, 107849
  ) ORDER BY execution_element_id DESC
```

##### Debug for this query:

***3.1 EXPLAIN***

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | execution_element_progress |  | range | execution_element_id | execution_element_id | 8 |  | 494 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Backward index scan; Using MRR |

***3.2 EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON***

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "591.61"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "execution_element_progress",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "execution_element_id"
        ],
        "key": "execution_element_id",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "execution_element_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "8",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 494,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 494,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "(`pm_prod`.`execution_element_progress`.`execution_element_id` in (29412,29413,49662,49663,49664,49665,54520,54522,105839,107267,107268,107269,107270,107279,107284,107285,107286,107303,107304,107305,107306,107307,107308,107309,107310,107320,107334,107427,107515,107688,107689,107690,107691,107692,107695,107802,107803,107804,107811,107812,107813,107849))",
        "backward_index_scan": true,
        "using_MRR": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "542.21",
          "eval_cost": "49.40",
          "prefix_cost": "591.61",
          "data_read_per_join": "65K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "uuid",
          "tenant_id",
          "execution_program_id",
          "execution_element_id",
          "execution_strategic_sprint_id",
          "execution_sprint_id",
          "value",
          "value_percent",
          "total",
          "total_percent",
          "target",
          "target_percent",
          "is_primary_value",
          "is_projection_value",
          "is_detached_from_sprints",
          "deleted_at",
          "deleted_by_user_id",
          "created_at",
          "created_by_user_id",
          "updated_at",
          "updated_by_user_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***3.3 EXPLAIN ANALYZE***

```
-> Index range scan on execution_element_progress using execution_element_id over (execution_element_id = 29412) OR (execution_element_id = 29413) OR (40 more) (reverse), with index condition: (execution_element_progress.execution_element_id in (29412,29413,49662,49663,49664,49665,54520,54522,105839,107267,107268,107269,107270,107279,107284,107285,107286,107303,107304,107305,107306,107307,107308,107309,107310,107320,107334,107427,107515,107688,107689,107690,107691,107692,107695,107802,107803,107804,107811,107812,107813,107849))  (cost=592 rows=494) (actual time=0.089..5.06 rows=486 loops=1)
```

#### 4. Select with MRR disabled

Now I also found out, that if I turn *off* **MRR**:

```sql
SET SESSION optimizer_switch='mrr=off';
```

And rerun the same query, it works:

```sql
select
  *
from
  `execution_element_progress`
where
  `execution_element_id` in (
    29412, 29413, 49662, 49663, 49664, 49665, 54520, 54522, 105839, 107267, 107268, 107269, 107270, 107279, 107284, 107285, 107286, 107303, 107304, 107305, 107306, 107307, 107308, 107309, 107310, 107320, 107334, 107427, 107515, 107688, 107689, 107690, 107691, 107692, 107695, 107802, 107803, 107804, 107811, 107812, 107813, 107849
  )
```

##### Debug for this query:

***4.1 EXPLAIN***

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | execution_element_progress |  | range | execution_element_id | execution_element_id | 8 |  | 494 | 100.00 | Using index condition |

***4.1 EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON***

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "631.70"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "execution_element_progress",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "execution_element_id"
      ],
      "key": "execution_element_id",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "execution_element_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "8",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 494,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 494,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "index_condition": "(`pm_prod`.`execution_element_progress`.`execution_element_id` in (29412,29413,49662,49663,49664,49665,54520,54522,105839,107267,107268,107269,107270,107279,107284,107285,107286,107303,107304,107305,107306,107307,107308,107309,107310,107320,107334,107427,107515,107688,107689,107690,107691,107692,107695,107802,107803,107804,107811,107812,107813,107849))",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "582.30",
        "eval_cost": "49.40",
        "prefix_cost": "631.70",
        "data_read_per_join": "65K"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "uuid",
        "tenant_id",
        "execution_program_id",
        "execution_element_id",
        "execution_strategic_sprint_id",
        "execution_sprint_id",
        "value",
        "value_percent",
        "total",
        "total_percent",
        "target",
        "target_percent",
        "is_primary_value",
        "is_projection_value",
        "is_detached_from_sprints",
        "deleted_at",
        "deleted_by_user_id",
        "created_at",
        "created_by_user_id",
        "updated_at",
        "updated_by_user_id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***4.1 EXPLAIN ANALYZE***

```
-> Index range scan on execution_element_progress using execution_element_id over (execution_element_id = 29412) OR (execution_element_id = 29413) OR (40 more), with index condition: (execution_element_progress.execution_element_id in (29412,29413,49662,49663,49664,49665,54520,54522,105839,107267,107268,107269,107270,107279,107284,107285,107286,107303,107304,107305,107306,107307,107308,107309,107310,107320,107334,107427,107515,107688,107689,107690,107691,107692,107695,107802,107803,107804,107811,107812,107813,107849))  (cost=632 rows=494) (actual time=0.15..4.37 rows=486 loops=1)
```

If I turn it back *on*, it again fails.

My local MySQL **version** is:
`mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for macos13.3 on arm64 (Homebrew)`

The MySQL version on UAT is:
`mysql  Ver 8.0.31 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

#### Test on another machine

To make sure it is not an issue with the dump itself, I imported it on a Windows 11 with WSL (`mysql  Ver 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`) and tried the queries also there. Surprise, there it is working!

Any help is highly appreciated!

### Edit

This is now a "fully verified bug report".
You can check the status [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=112642).

Comment: This sounds like a corrupted index, try repairing the table.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT... ` `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT... `for each.  If you don't get satisfaction here, get the Optimizer Trace and have that ready to put in a bugs.mysql.com report.

Comment: While the error should never occur, rebuilding the index may be a workaround.

Comment: @RickJames you mean these 4 eplain/analyze for all 3-4 queries, per each stage, local, uat and wsl and post it here? This would be a lot of data :D

Comment: Yeah, a lot of data.  And I probably won't be able to deduce anything from it all.  I _suspect_ there is an obscure bug somewhere in MySQL; the requested info should be supplied with the bug report.  I fear that you won't be able to write a test case took reproduce the problem.  Without such, a bug report will probably collect dust.

Comment: @RickJames now I added the debug information. Sorry it took so long... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the index on the machine where it fails.  If it still fails, please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com and include all(?) of what you have provided here, ulus a test case with data.

Comment: @RickJames I tried `ALTER TABLE execution_element_progress;` and `OPTIMIZE TABLE execution_element_progress;`. None of them worked. Okay so I'm gonna fill out the bug report...